# USB 2.0 Port Causing Weird Audio Artifacts on MP3 Player

Tags: windows, usb, audio, motherboard, mp3-player

I have a SanDisk Sansa Clip Zip 8 gb.  A little while ago, I built a new computer, and so far everything has been working fine, besides the USB 2.0 ports on the front.  The ports seem to work fine with anything other than the Sansa (reading, writing, etc).  But, when I tried to transfer some new music to the player, the music comes out with a ton of artifacts on both the audio (skipping, buzzing, loud noises, etc) and the album art (discoloration, banding).  Every time I transfer something, the artifacts change(the album art is different every time).  I can listen to music that I had on the player previously through the computer perfectly fine, and the device is recognized by Windows and everything.  I then plugged the device into the USB 3.0 ports on the front, and I can now transfer everything perfectly fine.

What I'm wondering, is what could cause the USB port to generate artifacts in only one way?  Could it be a problem with Windows (currently running Windows 7), the Motherboard (MSI A88XM-E35) or something completely different?

The entire build for the computer can be found [here](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/tinybob20/saved/pM7p99).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the [firmware version](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/Sansa-Clip-Sansa-Clip/Sansa-Clip-Firmware-01-01-35-amp-02-01-35-Release/td-p/144965) of the music player? By default, it should use the Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) when connected to Windows. Can you reproduce the issue if you switch to the Mass Storage Class mode (Menu > Settings > USB > MSC)?